How to override form_account layout block in magento2 admin
How to override form_account layout block in magento2 admin. I wanted to add a custom fiield under email field in account information section.

To add a custom field under the Email field in the Account Information section of the Magento 2 Admin Panel (Customer Edit page), you can override the layout block that controls the form_account and add your custom field there.
This involves modifying the layout and block structure, as well as extending or overriding the UI components used in the customer account form.
Steps to Override the form_account Layout Block and Add a Custom Field in Magento 2 Admin:
Step 1: Create a Custom Module
If you don't have a custom module, create one as follows:

Create your module directory:
app/code/BoostMyStore/CustomerCustomField/


Register your module with registration.php:
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'BoostMyStore_CustomerCustomField',
    __DIR__
);


Create module.xml under app/code/BoostMyStore/CustomerCustomField/etc/:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="BoostMyStore_CustomerCustomField" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>



Step 2: Override the Layout XML (customer_account_edit.xml)
Magento 2 uses UI components to render forms like the Account Information section in the Admin Panel.
The form_account block is defined in the customer_account_edit.xml layout file under:
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_form.xml

2.1. Create a Custom Layout XML:
To override this layout file and add a new field under the email field, create a new layout file in your module:
app/code/BoostMyStore/CustomerCustomField/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_form.xml

Inside this file, reference the existing fieldset and add your custom field under the email field:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="customer">
        <field name="email">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        
        <!-- Custom field added below the email field -->
        <field name="custom_field">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Field</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">custom_field</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>

Step 3: Extend the Customer Entity to Save the Custom Field Data
3.1. Add a Custom Field to the Customer Entity:

To add a custom field to the customer entity, you will need to create a setup script to modify the database schema. Create the InstallData.php or UpgradeData.php file if you want to install or upgrade the module.

Example InstallData.php:
<?php

namespace BoostMyStore\CustomerCustomField\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'custom_field',
            [
                'type'         => 'varchar',
                'label'        => 'Custom Field',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'required'     => false,
                'visible'      => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'position'     => 999,
                'system'       => 0,
                'backend'      => ''
            ]
        );

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'custom_field')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer'
            ]]);

        $attribute->save();
    }
}

3.2. Run the Setup Upgrade:
After creating the setup script, run the following command to execute the schema changes:
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Step 4: Modify the Customer Form to Display the Custom Field
Once the custom field is added in the database, you need to modify the customer_form.xml layout as explained above to include the field.
Step 5: Handle the Save Logic for the Custom Field
To save the custom field value, you don't need extra logic since Magento automatically handles EAV attributes. However, you need to ensure that the field is part of the form submission.
Step 6: Clear Cache and Verify
After all changes have been made, clear the cache and deploy static content if needed:
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Summary of Key Steps:

Create a custom module.
Override the customer_form.xml layout to add a custom field under the email field.
Add the custom field to the customer entity in the database (through setup script).
Display the custom field in the form by extending the layout XML.
Ensure the field saves in the admin.

By following this method, you'll be able to override the form_account block in Magento 2 admin and add your custom field under the email field in the Account Information section.

Create the module directory structure:
app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/
registration.php in app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/:
<?php
 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Vendor_ModuleName',
__DIR__
 );

Create module.xml in app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Vendor_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>

Create adminhtml_customer_account_edit.xml in app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/layout/
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_form">
        <action method="addField">
            <field name="custom_field" translate="label" sortOrder="10" formElement="input">
                <settings>
                    <dataType>text</dataType>
                    <label>Custom Field</label>
                    <dataScope>custom_field</dataScope>
                </settings>
            </field>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>

Create form.xml in app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="account_information">
    <field name="custom_field" formElement="input">
        <settings>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Custom Field</label>
            <dataScope>custom_field</dataScope>
            <required>false</required>
        </settings>
    </field>
</fieldset>
</form>

Run the following commands:
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 php bin/magento setup:di:compile 
 php bin/magento s:static-content:de -f
 php bin/magento cache:clean
 php bin/magento cache:flush

